# $f_n\to f$ uniformly if, and only if $M_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Theorem: Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f_n(x)=f(x)}$ and ($x\in E$). Let $M_n=\sup_{x\in E}|{f_n(x)-f(x}|$. Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly if, and only if $M_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$

This is a theorem on Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis. He doesn't give a detailed proof so I wanted to give it a try. This is what I got.

First assume $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Then $f_n$ also converges pointwise on E and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f_n(x)=f(x)}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{M_n}=\sup_{x\in E}|f(x)-f(x)|=0$.

For the converse, let's assume $M_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that when $n\geq N$ implies that $|M_n-0|=|M_n|\leq\epsilon$, but $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon$ for all $x\in E$. We conclude that $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the converse is good, but the first part is wrong. Pointwise convergence will not imply that the supremum goes to zero.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I couldn't work it out.

Comment: @TheMadMaxIV Your idea in the second part was good. You should do something like that in the first too. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @TheMadMaxIV It's helpful to write down what you have and what you want to prove. We have that $M_n \to 0$, which means that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n >N$ we have that $\sup |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. What do we want to prove? $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n >N$ we have that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon \forall x$. Can you see the connection?

Comment: For the first part we have that $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then for all $\epsilon$ and for all $x\in E$ there is an $N$ so that for $n>N$ this implies that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Because this is true for all $x\in E$ then for $n>N$ $M_n=sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon$? or maybe given the inequality $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ could we take the supremum on both sides?

Comment: @TheMadMaxIV yes. And since $M_n \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon$ eventually, we get that $M_n \to 0$ (because it's positive).